# A complex string splitter- How do I make this working code better?

Tags: c#

I have the below program

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Assembly> failedAssemblies = LoadAssembly();
            string batchFile = "D:\\1" + ".bat";
            FileStream fs = File.Create(batchFile);
            fs.Close();

            using (StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(batchFile))
            {
                string command = @"echo off";
                outFile.WriteLine(command);

                Process(outFile, failedAssemblies);

            }           
        }

        private static void Process(StreamWriter outFile, List<Assembly> assembliesList)
        {
            string command = "mstest.exe ";
            string testcontainer = " /testcontainer:";
            List<string> testContainerAssemblies = new List<string>(4);

            outFile.WriteLine("SET Path=%MsTestPath%");

            foreach (Assembly assmbly in assembliesList)
            {

                command = string.Empty;
                if (!testContainerAssemblies.Contains(assmbly.AssemblyName))
                {
                    outFile.WriteLine(' ');

                    testContainerAssemblies.Add(assmbly.AssemblyName);                   
                    command = "mstest.exe ";
                    command += testcontainer + "\\" + assmbly.AssemblyName + " ";
                    command += "/resultsfile:\"" + "\\Resultfile_" + assmbly.AssemblyName.Replace(".dll", "") + "_" + "1".ToString() + ".trx\"";
                    command += " /runconfig:";
                    command += " /detail:owner";
                    command += " /detail:duration";
                    command += " /detail:description";

                    command += " /unique ";
                }

                command += " /test:" + assmbly.NameSpaceName + "." + assmbly.ClassName + "." + assmbly.FunctionName;

                outFile.Write(command);
            }
        }


        private static List<Assembly> LoadAssembly()
        {
            var assemblyCollection = new List<Assembly>();

            assemblyCollection.Add(new Assembly { AssemblyName = "AccountTestBase.dll", NameSpaceName = "ECardTest", ClassName = "ECardTest", FunctionName = "ECardTestDownLoadPKGSuccess" });
            assemblyCollection.Add(new Assembly { AssemblyName = "AccountTestBase.dll", NameSpaceName = "AccountTest", ClassName = "IAccountTest", FunctionName = "Somefunc" });
            assemblyCollection.Add(new Assembly { AssemblyName = "TestPayment.dll", NameSpaceName = "TestPayment", ClassName = "CreditCardTestCases", FunctionName = "BoletoFunctionalTestCase" });
            assemblyCollection.Add(new Assembly { AssemblyName = "TestPayment.dll", NameSpaceName = "TestPayment", ClassName = "CreditCardTestCases", FunctionName = "BoletoEndToEndFunctionalTestCase" });
            assemblyCollection.Add(new Assembly { AssemblyName = "TestPayment.dll", NameSpaceName = "TestPayment", ClassName = "CreditCardTestCases", FunctionName = "BoletoPurcahseTestCase" });
            assemblyCollection.Add(new Assembly { AssemblyName = "TestPayment.dll", NameSpaceName = "TestPayment", ClassName = "CreditCardTestCases", FunctionName = "CreditCard_ResumeOrder_Success" });
            assemblyCollection.Add(new Assembly { AssemblyName = "TestPayment.dll", NameSpaceName = "TestPayment", ClassName = "CreditCardTestCases", FunctionName = "CreditCard_EURCurr_USBilling_ENUS" });
            assemblyCollection.Add(new Assembly { AssemblyName = "TestPayment.dll", NameSpaceName = "TestPayment", ClassName = "CreditCardTestCases", FunctionName = "DinersClubPayment" });

            return assemblyCollection;

        }
    }

    public class Assembly
    {
        public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public string FunctionName { get; set; }
        public string NameSpaceName { get; set; }

    }
```

It generates the below output

```
echo off
SET Path=%MsTestPath%

mstest.exe  /testcontainer:\AccountTestBase.dll /resultsfile:"\Resultfile_AccountTestBase_1.trx" /runconfig: /detail:owner /detail:duration /detail:description /unique  /test:ECardTest.ECardTest.ECardTestDownLoadPKGSuccess /test:AccountTest.IAccountTest.Somefunc 
mstest.exe  /testcontainer:\TestPayment.dll /resultsfile:"\Resultfile_TestPayment_1.trx" /runconfig: /detail:owner /detail:duration /detail:description /unique  /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.BoletoFunctionalTestCase /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.BoletoEndToEndFunctionalTestCase /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.BoletoPurcahseTestCase /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.CreditCard_ResumeOrder_Success /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.CreditCard_EURCurr_USBilling_ENUS /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.DinersClubPayment
```

Now a new requirement has come where we need to break the output based on the limits passed.

Say If the Limit is 300, the output will be

```
echo off
SET Path=%MsTestPath%

mstest.exe  /testcontainer:\AccountTestBase.dll /resultsfile:"\Resultfile_AccountTestBase_1.trx" /runconfig: /detail:owner /detail:duration /detail:description /unique  /test:ECardTest.ECardTest.ECardTestDownLoadPKGSuccess
mstest.exe  /testcontainer:\TestPayment.dll /resultsfile:"\Resultfile_TestPayment_1.trx" /runconfig: /detail:owner /detail:duration /detail:description /unique  /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.BoletoFunctionalTestCase /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.BoletoEndToEndFunctionalTestCase 

mstest.exe  /testcontainer:\TestPayment.dll /resultsfile:"\Resultfile_TestPayment_1.trx" /runconfig: /detail:owner /detail:duration /detail:description /unique /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.BoletoPurcahseTestCase /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.CreditCard_ResumeOrder_Success /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.CreditCard_EURCurr_USBilling_ENUS /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.DinersClubPayment
```

i.e. the firstone has a total character limit of 210(approx) and henceforth it remain the same.
The second one has crossed the limit and needs to be splited into two parts. The first one got a split over (290) because adding one more command to it will cross the limit.That's why we need to split it into two parts.

One more point to tell is that, we cannot just split precisely based on the Limit value provided. Because it is a MSTest command that needs to be run. Henceforth,

`"mstest.exe  /testcontainer:\TestPayment.dll /resultsfile:"\Resultfile_TestPayment_1.trx" /runconfig: /detail:owner /detail:duration /detail:description /unique"` will always come and then `"test/..."`

How to do the same in C#?

**MyShot(Please improve it)**

```
private static void Process(StreamWriter outFile, List<Assembly> failedAssemblies)
{
    int MAXLIMIT = 2000;
    string command = "mstest.exe ";
    string testcontainer = " /testcontainer:";
    List<string> testContainerAssemblies = new List<string>(4);
    int sum = 0;

    outFile.WriteLine("SET Path=%MsTestPath%");


    var failedAssemblyCollections = (from x in failedAssemblies
                                     group x by x.AssemblyName into g
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         AssemblyNames = g.Key,                                      
                                         FullyQualifiedTestMethods = g.Select(i => " /test:" + i.NameSpaceName + "." + i.ClassName + "." + i.FunctionName),
                                         FullyQualifiedTestMethodsLen = g.Select(i => Convert.ToString(" /test:" + i.NameSpaceName + "." + i.ClassName + "." + i.FunctionName).Length)
                                     });

        foreach (var item in failedAssemblyCollections)
        {
            var assemblyNames = item.AssemblyNames;
            var methodsLengths = item.FullyQualifiedTestMethodsLen.ToList();
            var flag = true;
            int counter = 0;

            //write for the very first time
            if (flag)
            {
                Write(outFile, ref command, testcontainer, assemblyNames);
                flag = false;
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < methodsLengths.Count; i++)
            {
                sum += methodsLengths[i];

                if (sum <= MAXLIMIT)
                {
                    command += item.FullyQualifiedTestMethods.ToList()[i];

                    //this will execute when a long command is splitted and is written in new trx files
                    if (flag)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        Write(outFile, ref command, testcontainer, assemblyNames);
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }


                //if the value crosses max limit
                //write the current output
                //then reset variables to original 
                if (sum >= MAXLIMIT)
                {
                    outFile.Write(command);
                    sum = 0;
                    flag = true;
                    i--;
                }
            }
            outFile.Write(command);

        }

}

private static void Write(StreamWriter outFile, ref string command, string testcontainer, string assemblyNames)
{
    outFile.WriteLine(' ');
    command = "mstest.exe ";
    command += testcontainer + "\\" + assemblyNames + " ";  
    command += " /runconfig:";
    command += " /detail:owner";
    command += " /detail:duration";
    command += " /detail:description";

    command += " /unique ";

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like a simple matter of checking length, checking indexes of `/test:` flags and spaces.

Comment: I have done the program...kindly help me to write a better one.It has been updated

Comment: Is there something specific about it? I would suggest if you want us to vaguely "write a better one" or "improve it", you ask on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). If you still want to do it here, I suggest marking this question as answered, starting a new question as you've changed this question from "How do I do this?" (which I answered), to "How do I make this working code better?"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.I have edited the question title also.Actually I have thought initially the same way as what u have suggested.The reason for being posted it in SO is to get some better idea.However, I will wait for some more answer to come for this with some new approach (I still hope that the program can be written in a better way).Equally I have posted the same to CodeReview by following ur suggestion.Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static void Process(StreamWriter outFile, List<Assembly> failedAssemblies)
{
    int MAXLIMIT = 2000;
    string command = "mstest.exe ";
    string testcontainer = " /testcontainer:";
    List<string> testContainerAssemblies = new List<string>(4);
    int sum = 0;

    outFile.WriteLine("SET Path=%MsTestPath%");


    var failedAssemblyCollections = (from x in failedAssemblies
                                     group x by x.AssemblyName into g
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         AssemblyNames = g.Key,                                      
                                         FullyQualifiedTestMethods = g.Select(i => " /test:" + i.NameSpaceName + "." + i.ClassName + "." + i.FunctionName),
                                         FullyQualifiedTestMethodsLen = g.Select(i => Convert.ToString(" /test:" + i.NameSpaceName + "." + i.ClassName + "." + i.FunctionName).Length)
                                     });

        foreach (var item in failedAssemblyCollections)
        {
            var assemblyNames = item.AssemblyNames;
            var methodsLengths = item.FullyQualifiedTestMethodsLen.ToList();
            var flag = true;
            int counter = 0;

            //write for the very first time
            if (flag)
            {
                Write(outFile, ref command, testcontainer, assemblyNames);
                flag = false;
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < methodsLengths.Count; i++)
            {
                sum += methodsLengths[i];

                if (sum <= MAXLIMIT)
                {
                    command += item.FullyQualifiedTestMethods.ToList()[i];

                    //this will execute when a long command is splitted and is written in new trx files
                    if (flag)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        Write(outFile, ref command, testcontainer, assemblyNames);
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }


                //if the value crosses max limit
                //write the current output
                //then reset variables to original 
                if (sum >= MAXLIMIT)
                {
                    outFile.Write(command);
                    sum = 0;
                    flag = true;
                    i--;
                }
            }
            outFile.Write(command);

        }

}

private static void Write(StreamWriter outFile, ref string command, string testcontainer, string assemblyNames)
{
    outFile.WriteLine(' ');
    command = "mstest.exe ";
    command += testcontainer + "\\" + assemblyNames + " ";  
    command += " /runconfig:";
    command += " /detail:owner";
    command += " /detail:duration";
    command += " /detail:description";

    command += " /unique ";

}
```

Comment: priyanka: I think you would want to queue your "verbs" and progressively dequeue them (along with a letter count check on each dequeue) like Chris is more or less doing.

Answer (score 0):

A *very* rough example I hammered out is here. I have not tested for edge cases such as: where the line length is very close to or exactly the limit, or when a single test case exceeds the limit. I'll leave those exercises to you.

Sometimes the easiest is just to write out unit tests, spit out standard loops and length checks to pass those tests, then play around with LINQ or regex or a code cleanup to get something maintainable and readable.

```
string input = @"mstest.exe  /testcontainer:\TestPayment.dll /resultsfile:""\Resultfile_TestPayment_1.trx"" /runconfig: /detail:owner /detail:duration /detail:description /unique  /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.BoletoFunctionalTestCase /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.BoletoEndToEndFunctionalTestCase /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.BoletoPurcahseTestCase /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.CreditCard_ResumeOrder_Success /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.CreditCard_EURCurr_USBilling_ENUS /test:TestPayment.CreditCardTestCases.DinersClubPayment";

const int LINE_LIMIT = 300;
const string TEST_MARKER = " /test:";

int testIndex = input.IndexOf(TEST_MARKER);
string prefix = input.Substring(0, testIndex);
int availableCharacters = LINE_LIMIT - prefix.Length;

Queue<string> tests = new Queue<string>(input.Substring(testIndex).Split(new []{TEST_MARKER}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

List<string> testSets = new List<string>();
string currentTest = "";
while (tests.Count > 0)
{
    //restores the test marker from splitting
    string test = TEST_MARKER + tests.Dequeue(); 

    if (currentTest.Length + test.Length > availableCharacters)
    {
        testSets.Add(currentTest);
        currentTest = "";
    }
    else
    {
        currentTest += test;
    }
}

if (currentTest != "")
{
    testSets.Add(currentTest);
}

var lines = testSets.Select(t => prefix + t).ToList(); //your line outputs
```